# Substituir valor NaN no dataFrame por uma string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Olá , estou desenvolvendo um pequeno DataFrame que armazena o nome e o símbolo de alguns ácidos.
Já fiz o código que gera o DataFrame como duas séries separadas e concateno eles na variável DF.

Porém queria saber como posso inserir uma string numa posição específica desse DataFrame?

Por exemplo, como substituir a linha 6, coluna Fórmulas dos Ácidos por uma string que vai conter uma fórmula genérica?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame





NomesdosÁcidos=pd.Series(["Ácido Permangânico", "Ácidos Fosforoso",
                          "Ácido Oxálico", "Ácido Sulforoso",
                          "Ácido Arsênico",
                          "Ácido ortossilícico", "Ácido Fosfórico", "Ácido nitroso", "Ácido nítrico",
                          "Ácido hipofosforoso", "Ácido pirofosfórico",
                          "Ácido cloroso"
                          "Ácido perlórico", "Ácido clórico","Ácido Sulfúrico"])
NomesdosÁcidos


FórmulasdosÁcidos=pd.Series(["H\N{Subscript Three}PO\N{Subscript Three}",
                             "HMnO\N{Subscript Four}", 
                             "H\N{Subscript Two}C\N{Subscript Two}O\N{Subscript Four}",
                             "H\N{Subscript Two}SO\N{Subscript Three}",
                             "H\N{Subscript Three}AsO\N{Subscript Four}",
                             "Si(OH)\N{Subscript Four}"])
FórmulasdosÁcidos

df = DataFrame({"Nomes dos Ácidos": NomesdosÁcidos, "Fórmulas dos Ácidos": FórmulasdosÁcidos})
df


df.isnull() # Mostra quantos elementos estão faltando no dataFrame
df.isnull().sum() # Soma a quantidade de elementos faltantes em cada coluna


--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Solução para o problema 



    df.isnull() # Mostra quantos elementos estão faltando no dataFrame
    df.isnull().sum() # Soma a quantidade de elementos faltantes em cada coluna
    df.loc[[6], 'Fórmulas dos Ácidos'] = 'H\N{Subscript Three}PO\N{Subscript Four}' # O método df.loc substitui um valor da linha e da coluna especificada pela variável atribuída pelo usuário. 
    df.loc[[7], 'Fórmulas dos Ácidos'] = 'HNO\N{Subscript Two}'
    df.loc[[8,9], 'Fórmulas dos Ácidos'] = 'formula 1', 'formula2'
 # Pode ser feito mais de uma vez em sequência.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo ao titulo do pergunta, podes usar o método [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
...
df = df.fillna('fórmula genérica')
...
```

Ou:

```
...
df.fillna('fórmula genérica', inplace=True) # atribui o novo valor ao df teres de lhe atribuir explicitamente o valor
...
```

Output:

```
   Fórmulas dos Ácidos              Nomes dos Ácidos
0                H₃PO₃            Ácido Permangânico
1                HMnO₄              Ácidos Fosforoso
2               H₂C₂O₄                 Ácido Oxálico
3                H₂SO₃               Ácido Sulforoso
4               H₃AsO₄                Ácido Arsênico
5              Si(OH)₄           Ácido ortossilícico
6     fórmula genérica               Ácido Fosfórico
7     fórmula genérica                 Ácido nitroso
8     fórmula genérica                 Ácido nítrico
9     fórmula genérica           Ácido hipofosforoso
10    fórmula genérica           Ácido pirofosfórico
11    fórmula genérica  Ácido clorosoÁcido perlórico
12    fórmula genérica                 Ácido clórico
13    fórmula genérica               Ácido Sulfúrico
```

Respondendo ao problema em si, para editares apenas em uma(s) linha(s):

```
...
df.loc[[6,7], 'Fórmulas dos Ácidos'] = 'formula 1' # substuir as linhas 6 e 7
...
```

Comment: Porém daí ele substituiria tudo que ficou NaN pela mesma fórmula, é possível eu ir substituindo manualmente cada índice com o mesmo método?

Comment: Editei @CaioVinicius

Comment: Vou testar esse método df.loc! Parece ser exatamente o que eu precisava. :) Já edito

Comment: Consegui ! :D 

Muito obrigadooo!

Comment: Ajudou e muito, como faço para aceitar? :) Sou novo no stackoverflow

Comment: Acho que descobri como se faz isso, hahah. Obrigado Miguel!

Comment: É isso mesmo @CaioVinicius. Bem-vindo